# Point Android Google Maps SDK to http://maps.google.cn

Tags: android, google-maps

So we have a mapping feature in our application but at present it is not functional with in China.

I was wondering is there some way to point the google maps sdk to the

`http://maps.google.cn`

So that it is accessible with in China?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps APIs are served within China from the domain maps.google.cn. This domain does not support https. When making requests to the Google Maps APIs from China, please replace //maps.googleapis.com with //maps.google.cn.

For example:

//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
would become:

//maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
The Google Maps JavaScript API can be loaded with the following bootstrap:

`<script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
type="text/javascript">
</script>`

For additional details refer to here [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#china_ws_access)

Comment: This works for the JavaScript API, I am using the Android SDK. I was hoping there is a way to allow the SDK to use the maps.google.cn interface